# How do I resolve this Bad Gateway error with my local NginX web site?

Tags: php, nginx

I am running a local testing server on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.10. I was running Apache2, but I've decided to switch over to NginX. I have five sites, one is just plain HTML, the others are PHP 7.

The site that is just HTML is working fine. The PHP sites are failing. At first, the PHP based sites were all returning a `403 Forbidden` error, as described in [this question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41500932/184108).

However, after some experiments and looking at documentation on the web, it seemed maybe the problem was that the NginX configuration files for each site were pointing to `index.html`, not `index.php`. So, I changed the configuration files from this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

... to this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Unfortunately, that only changed the kind of error I get. Now, when I load one of my PHP sites, I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error, and this is what shows up in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2017/01/07 17:28:26 [crit] 6308#6308: *9 connect() to unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecti
ng to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: local_examle.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.
sock:", host: "local_example.com"
```

I thought I had php7.0-fpm installed and configured correctly, but I guess somehow NginX and PHP are not working together on my system.

**How do I resolve this `Bad Gateway` error and get my PHP based web sites to work on NginX?**

Comment: Make sure the path of php7.0-fpm is correct, in all config files.

Comment: @Nitin, thank you for responding. Could you be more specific about which config files, though? I'm new to NginX, so I'm not familiar enough to just assume which files would be relevant.

Comment: `php-fpm` listens using a unix socket (that's the file) or TCP socket (something like 127.0.0.1:9000). What happens in your case is that you're telling nginx to proxy request to where PHP is **not** listening. You have to determine which socket PHP uses to accept requests. Once done, change your `fastcgi_pass` directive to that socket and `sudo service nginx reload`. How did you install PHP? Was it from a repository or did you compile it?

Comment: @N.B., Thank you for responding. I just installed PHP from the standard Ubuntu repository. I am not expert enough to compile anything, and I don't really know how to determine sockets. I'm more of a website developer than a server admin, trying to set up a system to I can develop websites. Which is just to say that I don't have so much expertise about these matters.

Comment: Ok, I'll expand into answer but my method of solving this isn't exactly the best but it should get you going.

Comment: Also check if socket file is actually in /run/php then like N.B. suggested update and maintain same location in both config files: /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and /etc/nginx/sites-available/sitename.conf. – and make sure the settings are correct in sitename.conf. or check out this link for the best installation instructions https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why do you get the error in the first place

You're getting the error because `nginx` is proxying request to a nonexistent endpoint. Basically, it never reaches PHP. That's what we need to fix.

What tells us the error lies in that is this:

`[crit] 6308#6308: *9 connect() to unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock`

### Steps we're taking

- ensuring `php-fpm` works
- finding out where `php-fpm` is accepting connections at
- modifying nginx config to reflect the above

#### Ensuring PHP-FPM works

What I do is checking whether `php-fpm` process is in the process list. That tells me whether `php-fpm` started.

In your terminal, type:

`ps aux | grep php`

That shows you the list of php processes. If PHP-FPM isn't there, it means it never started so you can start it with

`sudo service php7.0-fpm start`. I assumed that `php7.0-fpm` is the name of the service.

If `php-fpm` IS there, you can always look at file descriptors it has open. This includes config files, libraries, network connections and unix sockets.

First, you need to find the `process ID` or PID of your `php-fpm` process. Output of `ps aux | grep php` will give you a list, you want to look at the process whose owner is `root` (it *usually* says that if you used defaults for 16.04).

#### Where PHP-FPM is accepting connections at

We'll list open file descriptors using `sudo lsof -p 123456` where `123456` is the process ID you obtained from `ps aux | grep php`.

Scroll down the list, you're looking for "unix" or "tcp" to see what it does.

#### Changing where PHP-FPM is accepting connections at

We can change the above value or you can keep it. Reason I went through the trouble to show these few useful commands was to highlight that you can always ask your system what's going on.

**IF** you know where config file is for your *pool* (usually `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` then open it and find `listen` directive. Change that or keep it, but use it in `nginx`'s `fastcgi_pass` value.

I wrote a lot, but it's only a few commands which you'll get familiar eventually if you keep using Linux. It's nothing overly difficult so I hope this won't turn you away from this method of serving PHP. I'd post more info but I'm not near a Linux machine at this moment so I didn't post terminal outputs for examples. I'll do it later if you don't find this answer useful without it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful answer. I followed your instructions, but I'm sorry to say I still ended up a little lost. I found a reference to `unix` in the `ps aux` output, but I wasn't clear on what to do with it. Similarly, I found the `listen` directive in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, as you described, but there was no obvious place to put `fastcgi_pass` value. There were only references to `www-data` and `0660`. I posted the output of the commands you suggested, plus the contents of `www.conf` [here](/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf).

Comment: I looked a little more, and I realized the line that must be relevant in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` is `listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`. However, if I understand the rest of your explanation, that should be the correct place for listening for PHP, because it matches the output of `lsof`. So something else must be amiss.

Comment: @Questioner that's good, this means PHP is running and the rest of the problem is determining why `nginx`  is not proxying http request there. Can you post your entire nginx config for that site please? It seems that parts might be missing.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I posted the site's config file [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23757648/). I hope it reveals something useful.

Comment: You wrote that `www.conf` contains `listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` but your `nginx` config file states this: `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;` - note the difference in paths, `/var/run` vs `/run`

Comment: Ah! Thank you for that catch. I've not set everything to use `/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock`and now there's.... progress? Now when I load the sites, I get a blank screen. No error, nothing in the error log, nothing. I put an `info.php` file in my root... but, nothing. I'm not sure if this means I've solved the PHP problem and uncovered another problem, or if PHP is still not configured correctly :/

Comment: Got it! After a little digging around on the web, I found that I also had to make the following changes to my site configuration files. One was to change this `fastcgi_index index.php;` to `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`. I also had to move `index index.php` to up near the top, and change it to `index index.php index.html index.htm;`. Now my sites are working! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.